# What does adding a reference to csproj file do?

Tags: c#, dllimport, csproj, dll-reference

Would it be accurate to say that a given DLL contains a bunch of namespaces (With classes, constants, functions etc. in each), and that referencing the dll in a csproj allows using them in .cs files belonging to that project?

I tried searching the web, but was unable to find answers which satisfied me. (Probably because the question is very basic)

Comment: Yes, that would be correct.

Comment: Yes, that's what it means - it is essentially "I want to consume this stuff in this module here"; note that it is increasingly common to use package references (to sources like NuGet) rather than assembly references - especially in the "new new csproj" world. Same concept, different logistics.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Call function from DLL?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5010957/call-function-from-dll)

Comment: @Default That is not a duplicate of that. The PO was not asking **how** to add a reference.

Comment: @Default - This is not a duplicate of Dominik Antal's question "Call function from DLL?". Firstly, since the referred question does not deal with projects, but standalone c# scripts. In addition, it only discusses calling functions form DLL, while referencing a dll allows accessing more than functions.

Comment: @KobyDouek if you read it reversed it does sound like a duplicate to me. the answer to that question says: "Add the DLL via the solution explorer then it should be available." Which is what OP is asking ("what happends when I add a DLL?") and the question in the duplicate is basically "I'm trying to [use a] DLL [..] in my program." which is thus the answer.

Comment: @yuvalm2 none of the questions are referring to any scripts.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The simple answer to your question is **yes**.

In order to use an external or a 3rd party component in your IDE, you must first add a reference to it.

Once you added an assembly reference, you will be able to use its methods and properties in your code, by explicitly referring to them:

```
someNamespace.someClass.someMethod();
```

Or by using the `using` statement at the beginning of your code file and simplifying the reference call:

```
using someNamespace.someClass;

someMethod();
```

---

**Adding a reference** (in Visual Studio)

To add a reference in Visual Studio, right click the "references" folder > choose "add reference" and then "Browse" to you DLL.

---

**Examining existing references**

In Visual Studio, in the Project Explorer Pane, you can view the details about a reference (such as the version and its location) by expanding the References folder, right-clicking a reference, and selecting Details.

Answer (score 1):

**Thats correct.**

When we add a reference of an existing project / dll (normally using visual studio) its entry is added into the `.csproj` file.

One of the web project's csproj file  I was working on that has dependency on the DataAccess project is shown below:

```
...
    <ItemGroup>
        <ProjectReference Include="..\WebStore.DataAccess\WebStore.DataAccess.csproj">
          <Project>{D7FBB6E0-C321-4BB3-A3D7-A78UUU04887E}</Project>
          <Name>WebStore.DataAccess</Name>
        </ProjectReference>
//    ... other references...
      </ItemGroup>
```

I would presume the same would be true for VB.Net projects.
Hope this helps!

Comment: VB.Net isn't mentioned. OP is using C#.

Comment: @Default that is correct! Since this is a public website, I was thinking may be someone else would benifit from this.