# Managed c++ code for C#

Tags: c++, .net, visual-studio

I am trying to set my settings in Visual Studio such that I can write managed `C++` code to be called later by a `C#` program. I start with a new `C++` project and here are the settings that I have changed and why:

- **Precompiled Headers** to `not using precompiled headers`. As I just would rather not.
- **Common Language Runtime Support** to `/clr`. As I understand it this is fundamentally needed.
- **Debugging Information Format** from `/ZI` to `none`. As `/clr` and `/ZI` are incompatible
- **Enable minimal rebuild** to `no`. As `/clr` and `/Gm` are incompatible.
- **Basic runtime checks** to `default`. As `/clr` and `/RTC1` are incompatible.

After all this I now come across many **C2760** error codes located in `xlocale` or `xlocnum`. The error specifically states

> syntax error: unexpected token 'identifier', expected 'catch'

Now, I am an extreme beginner here so maybe this is trivial and if so I apologize. My goal is to write a simple `c++ class`, wrap it with managed code, and have a `DLL` that I can link with a `c#` program later.

When I look at the MSDN Documentation page, all they say is to compile with `/clr` and `/LD`. Well there is no `/LD` option that I am able to find either, and I know that the `/LD` option is to create the `DLL` which is important. Any help or guidance would be greatly appreciated.

**P.S.** This is Visual Studio Community 2017

Comment: You are an extreme beginner, and want to write managed C++, and call it from C#.  You've set yourself quite the learning challenge!  You may find this Q&A useful in your endeavor: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5010957/call-function-from-dll

Comment: If your only goal is to share code between multiple .NET projects, a C# class library will work nicely and is much easier to accomplish.

Comment: @NightOwl888 my ultimate goal is really just to learn how it works. For example if a complicated class already exists in one language that can follow .Net framework, it might be easier to wrap that class rather than re-write the entire class. Does that make sense?

Comment: Yes it makes sense if you have the time to learn and want to add it to your skill set. Certainly, consuming 3rd party C++ libraries to reuse functionality is easier than building your own C++ libraries. Just wanted to make sure you realize there is a much quicker way if you had a tight deadline.

Answer (score 0):

Truth is: you have to have 2 projects.

1. Just old good C/C++ project. You may put a 3rd-party library here like OpenSSL or any other cross-platform source. Here you may have some challenge to remove/wrap any platform-specific code.
2. Windows Runtime Component - this is exactly CLI code that acts like bridge between native C/C++ and managed C#. You can find this at File -> New project, then Visual C++ -> Windows Universal. General idea about the Runtime Component is you can seamlessly import CLI methods by signature into C# code, you can call C# callbacks right at the CLI code, all C#/CLI types are binary-compatible etc. This is why you can not "just add specially configured C/C++ project".